# Gtk.ListStore(*datatypes) string error

Tags: pygtk

```
self.ip_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(*datatypes)
```

where

```
datatypes = [str,str,str]
```

I have also tried

```
datatypes = ['gchararray','gchararray']
```

And the interpreter replies with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gtktutorial.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
File "./gtktutorial.py", line 119, in main
[str,str,str,str,str,str,str])
File "./gtktutorial.py", line 37, in __init__
self.ip_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(*datatypes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 943, in __init__
self.set_column_types(column_types)
TypeError: Item 0: Must be gobject.GType, not str
```

What happens after the list is unpacked? Are the contents converted to strings? Is there something I don't know about unpacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is just a little confusion, and I remember I had a wrong time searching for it.

This is what I do :

```
self.searchCols     = ["Object", "Index", "Date", "Program", "Person", "Mode"]
sequence            = [str] * len(self.searchCols)
self.resultStore    = gtk.ListStore( * sequence )
self.resView        = gtk.TreeView(self.resultStore)
self.resView.cell   = [None] * len(self.searchCols)
rvcolumn            = [None] * len(self.searchCols)
for colnum, col in enumerate ( self.searchCols ) :
    self.resView.cell[colnum] = gtk.CellRendererText()
    rvcolumn[colnum] = gtk.TreeViewColumn(col, self.resView.cell[colnum])
    rvcolumn[colnum].add_attribute(self.resView.cell[colnum], 'text', colnum)
    self.resView.append_column(rvcolumn[colnum])
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Your code helped me to unpack my variables in the correct way. Thank you.